How to write a name of competition in an article?
Hi I am translating text from Polish to English. I would like to ask you about your thoughts on it:

A title of a newspaper is in Polish, do I need to add quotation marks or italics?
The name of competition in Polish is Nauczyciel Roku, the same question here italics or quotation marks?
Institutions can gain a status Szkoła na medal, italics or quotation marks?

Do you have any other idea, if so please provide me with links to authentic sources.

Does this answer your question? Multiple instances of the same (foreign) word [... italicizing ] (CMoS style is given. Also, MLA.)

... Or, better, punctuation guide for foreign words ... single or double quotation marks ...?.

This article gives the names of several French newspapers in italics. Quotation marks are usually used for titles only when italics are not possible, e.g. in handwriting. Whether or not you translate the name is your decision.
I see that the translation of the competition's name is Teacher of the Year. As this isn't the title of a work, capital letters are sufficient. I would suggest the same treatment for the name of an award. (Compare Horse of the Year Show, Carnegie Medal.)
